# The Logic for checking grid view cell values

Tags: .net, validation, gridview

If a cell value is duplicated in any of the other column cells, pop up an error.

Comment: What do you mean by this no proper data please update the question with more input

Answer (score 0):

MSDN has some examples of how to [validate the gridview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykdxa0bc%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) cell values, but instead of checking for an empty value, [iterate through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681046/programatically-loop-through-a-datagridview-and-check-checkboxes) the other cells, and assert when your comparison is true. There are many other [gridview examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) too.